# How could I run this dockerized app in development mode?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

The fronted is made with create-react-app and the backend is Node.js with Firebase.
This is my folder structure:

```
my-app
├── docker-compose.yml
├── client
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
├── server
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true

  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

**client/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://server:5000",
  "secure": false
}
```

**client/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /client

COPY package*.json /client/

RUN npm install

COPY . /client/

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**server/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "snake-react-node",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./build/index.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.56",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

**server/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /server

COPY package*.json /server/

RUN npm install

COPY . /server/

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I run `docker-compose up` on the root directory, two images and two containers get created, one for each Dockerfile. The app runs flawlessly and a production build is created but I would like to be able to use Docker for development too, with live reloads

Answer (score 0):

Since your `server` container publishes `ports:` out, you can change the proxy settings in your `package.json` file to point at this.  In your non-Docker host development environment, set

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

and then you can `npm run dev` to have a totally ordinary local live-reloading development server, targeting your backend service that's running in Docker.

There's not really any technical benefits to trying to simulate a local development environment inside a Docker container, especially for a browser-based application.  A typical Webpack-based build toolchain doesn't have complex native dependencies that would require special setup, and since the application itself runs in the browser, it can't take advantage of Docker networking and the container itself doesn't provide any of the application's runtime environment.  So the only real difference between running the dev server on the host vs. in a container is which version of Node the Webpack build is using, and hopefully this isn't a substantial difference to your application.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your answer (I'm very new to Docker). I have ```"proxy": "http://server:5000"``` on the client's ```package.json``` and it works: the frontend is sending an HTTP request to the backend and receiving information from the database. But I don't have live reloads on the frontend (React) or the backend (Node.js with TypeScript).

Comment: From the host you should be able to `curl http://localhost:5000` to reach the backend.  So set that as the proxy address, and `npm run dev` _without involving Docker_ for day-to-day development.

Comment: Oh, WITHOUT involving Docker. Yeah, I know that, it's what I have been using to develop the application before dockerizing it. But I want to run it in local development mode with Docker to simplify my workflow, from development to deployment. I was using Heroku for hosting but it needs a specific folder structure and commands. I added TypeScript to my backend and immediately struggled to get it to compile, build, and start. With Docker it's way easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind volume mounts for dev live reload. Make another dev compose file like `docker-compose-dev.yml` and add the `volumes:` section.

Whenever code is changed on the host machine using your favorite IDE, the container will pick it up and do the hot reload.

Note: I haven't tested this setup. Just suggesting something you could do.

#docker-compose-dev.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    build: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./frontend-src:/client/src
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true

  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Comment: I have added what you suggest, changing only ```volumes: - ./frontend-src:/client/src``` to ```volumes: - ./client:/src``` and running it with ```docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up``` from the root directory but I still don't have live reloads on either frontend or backend.